# Change the values for multiple columns of a data frame to NA that are located within the range of two vectors

Tags: r, replace, apply, multiple-columns, na

Using R: I want to change the values for each column of my `df` which are located within the range of the corresponding columns from my other dataframes to NA.

It works when I have only one column each:

```
df<
 days  X1 
    1  20     
    2  30     
    3  50    
    4  10 
    5  10  
    6  20 
    7  10  
    8  70 
    9  90 
    10 20 

start_vec<-c(4) 

end_vec<-c(8)
```

by using:

```
df[df$days %in% start_vec:end_vec, ]<-NA
```

where I get:

```
desired_df<
 days  X1 
    1  20     
    2  30     
    3  50    
    NA NA 
    NA NA  
    NA NA 
    NA NA  
    NA NA 
    9  90 
    10 20
```

But actually I have a dataframe with more than three columns and more than three different starting and ending vectors, as you can see here:

```
df
days   X1 X2 X3 Xn 
    1  20 10 20 ...   
    2  30 50 40 ...    
    3  50 40 40 ...  
    4  10 70 20 ...
    5  10 10 30 ...
    6  20 80 50 ...
    7  10 30 70 ... 
    8  70 10 10 ...
    9  90 10 70 ...
    10 20 50 10 ...

start_vec<-c(4,5,2,n)

end_vec<-c(8,9,7,n)
```

my desired dataframe is this:

```
desired_df<

days   X1 X2 X3 Xn
    1  20 10 20 ...   
    2  30 50 NA ...   
    3  50 40 NA ...  
    4  NA 70 NA ...
    5  NA NA NA ...
    6  NA NA NA ...
    7  NA NA NA ...
    8  NA NA 10 ...
    9  90 NA 70 ...
    10 20 50 10 ...
```

Where NAs for X1 of `df` are defined by the range between 1st `start_vec` and 1st `end_vec`.
X2 of `df` is defined by the range between 2nd `start_vec` and 2nd `end_vec` and so on...
I would need a function that works for n columns, since my original data frame has more than 100 columns. For each column I have the corresponding vectors.

I tried with `apply` in order to apply condition to every column:

```
desired_df<-apply(df, 2, function(x) x[df$days %in% start_vec:end_vec]<-NA)
```

What I get is a df with NAs only.

Do you have any idea how I can change the values for each column of my `df` to NA where `days` or the `index` is within the range of the corresponding vectors?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO!
There seem to be several problems here, first of all that the paranthesis in your last line of code dont match and that you seem to have a typo in df$yday. Also, how do you want to match the values in your start- and end-vector to the columns in your df? At the moment you dont match anything, so start_df:end_df cannot work (as they are dfs, not values).
Could you provide some fully-executable code, including variable creation?

Comment: try `desired_df<-df%>%mutate(X1=ifelse(days %in% starts_df$V1:end_df$Z1,"NA",X1), X2=ifelse(days %in% starts_df$V2:end_df$Z2,"NA",X2), X3=ifelse(days %in% starts_df$V3:end_df$Z3,"NA",X3)`

Comment: @Yann thank you very much for your comment! I edited my question. I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  days = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L),
  X1 = c(20L, 30L, 50L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 70L, 90L, 20L),
  X2 = c(10L, 50L, 40L, 70L, 10L, 80L, 30L, 10L, 10L, 50L),
  X3 = c(20L, 40L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 70L, 10L, 70L, 10L)
)

start_df <- c(4, 5, 2)

end_df <- c(8, 9, 7)

mat <-
  data.frame(row = c(4:8, 5:9, 2:7), col = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 6)))

df[-1][as.matrix(mat[, c("row", "col")])] <- NA
df
#>    days X1 X2 X3
#> 1     1 20 10 20
#> 2     2 30 50 NA
#> 3     3 50 40 NA
#> 4     4 NA 70 NA
#> 5     5 NA NA NA
#> 6     6 NA NA NA
#> 7     7 NA NA NA
#> 8     8 NA NA 10
#> 9     9 90 NA 70
#> 10   10 20 50 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>